# What explains the discrepancy in these two portrayals?

Tags: edge-chronicles

At the end of *The Immortals*, one of the later books in The Edge Chronicles, we see a schematic of the Edge cliff, serving essentially as a teaser for the awaited descent:

[image]

It seems to show a long slope beyond Riverrise, and the Edge cliff near Sanctphrax curving down into a plain.

However, in *The Descenders*, we see a totally different different schematic and description of the Edge Cliff:

> [image]

It doesn't look at all the same, even in the broad strokes.

That is:

> There is no plain at the bottom of the Edge: rather, the Edge itself is formed by glister condensation and is glisters all the way down; there is nothing but a steep drop beyond Riverrise.

Why is this? Are they actually consistent somehow? Did the authors have a change of heart during the writing process?

Comment: Is the second more of a diagram of the profile explaining "how it works" and the first a depiction of what it actually looks like? (Not read the work so going solely off by what I can see here).

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - They differ in more than that. In the first one, there's something flat at the bottom, very clearly, seemingly rock. In the second one, there's nothing but clouds and glisters.

Comment: Presumably the author just changed their minds. That happens

Comment: @Valorum - That could be, but I would like an statement if possible. It's also possible that they always had this in mind but were misleading, that I misunderstood the images, or that there's something in the story I missed.

Comment: For instance, one possible explanation is that the first figure is off, and the plane is supposed to be the beginning of the scree field. That would fit with the scale, although the shape would be way off.